# Ориентация поворота круглого изображения в SVG progress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, smil

Я пытаюсь создать круглый индикатор выполнения (как показано на изображении ниже). Прогрессия основана на процентах и будет двигаться по кругу до этого процента.

У меня прогрессия (линия) движется, но иконка, который движется вместе с ней, должна иметь правильную ориентацию. Как показано на изображении ниже, нижняя часть изображения обращена к центру, тогда как она должна быть обращена к нижней части экрана. Изображения должны двигаться вместе с полосой.

```html
<div class="case_progress_wrapper" data-percent="80">
 <svg class="case_progress_circle" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 140 140">
  <circle id="case_progress__path" cx="70" cy="70" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#EBEDF8" stroke-width="1" />
  <circle class="case_progress__value" cx="70" cy="70" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="6" />
  <circle class="case_progress__inner" cx="70" cy="70" r="44" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" />
  <circle class="case_progress__start" cx="124" cy="63" r="3" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" />
  <g id='case_progress__prog_fill' class="case_progress__prog" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
    <circle fill="url(#image)" cx="124" cy="63" r="8" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" />
  </g>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="60" height="60" xlink:href="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
 </svg>
</div>
```

```
(function(){
            var $wrapper = $('.case_progress_wrapper'),
                $progress = $('.case_progress__value'),
                $circle_path = $('#case_progress__path'),
                $complete_circle = $('.case_progress__prog'),
                $percent = $wrapper.data('percent');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $progress.css('transition', 'all 2s');
                $progress.css('stroke-dashoffset', 'calc(339.292 - (' + $percent + ' * 339.292 / 100))');
                $complete_circle.css('transition', 'all 2s');
                $complete_circle.attr("transform", 'rotate(' + (360 - ($percent - 25)) + ',' + $circle_path.attr('cx') + ',' + $circle_path.attr('cy') +')');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $progress.css('transition', 'none');
                    $complete_circle.css('transition', 'all 2s');
                }, 2000);

            }, 1000);

        })();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG progress circle image rotation orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64718677/7394871) от участника  [@Bryan88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1433742/bryan88).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64718677/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Решение на pure SVG и немного JS для вывода процентов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как и в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64717060/7394871)

Для решения, Вам нужно объединить две анимации:

*1. Анимация заполнения дуги от начала до конца*

Изменяется атрибут `stroke-dashoffset`

```
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
   begin="0s" dur="10s" values="339.5;0" fill="freeze" />
```

*2. Анимация движения окружности с иконкой внутри*

Движение иконки по той же окружности, у которой идёт заполнение красным цветом

```
<animateMotion begin="0s" dur="10s" fill="freeze"   >
   <mpath xlink:href="#case_progress__path" /> 
   </animateMotion>
```

Для синхронности анимаций установите одинаковое время выполнения

Прочитайте пожалуйста комментарии в коде.

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 10000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case_progress_wrapper" data-percent="80" style="width:50vw; height:50vh;">
 <svg class="case_progress_circle"  viewBox="0 0 140 140">
<defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="1 0 58 58">
      <image  x="0%" y="0%" width="60" height="60" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQMJ3.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#87CEEB" />
 <g transform="rotate(-90 70 70)" >  
    <!-- Трек для вращения круга с изображением -->
 <path id="case_progress__path"       
     style="fill:none;stroke:#ebedf8;stroke-width:1"
     d="M 124,70 A 54,54 0 0 1 70,124 54,54 0 0 1 16,70 54,54 0 0 1 70,16 54,54 0 0 1 124,70 Z"/>
  
   <!-- Красная окружность роста  прогресс бара -->
 <circle  
  class="case_progress__value" stroke-dashoffset="339.5" stroke-dasharray="339.5" cx="70" cy="70" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="6" >
     <!-- Анимация прогресс бара -->
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="10s" values="339.5;0" fill="freeze" /> 
    </circle> 
 <!-- Точка старта -->
<circle class="case_progress__start" cx="124" cy="70" r="3" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" />
  <g id='case_progress__prog_fill' class="case_progress__prog" viewBox="1 0 58 58">
  <circle transform="rotate(90 0 0)" fill="url(#image)" cx="0" cy="0"  r="8" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="#fff"   > 
      <!-- Анимация вращения иконки -->
        <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="10s" fill="freeze"   >
      <mpath xlink:href="#case_progress__path" /> 
      </animateMotion> 
  </circle>
  </g>  
    </g>

 <circle class="case_progress__inner" cx="70" cy="70" r="44" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" />
  <text id="count" x="50%" y="50%" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">100%</text>
 </svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722076/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>