# Как реализовать закругленную дугу с процентом?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как реализовать закругленную дугу с процентом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1202853/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1338054/178576)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ориентация поворота круглого изображения в SVG progress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202853/%d0%9e%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-svg-progress)